# Check MySql table for Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do I check if a table contains a specific row? I have a table organised as follows:

```
Follower        | Following      | Time
steve@gmail.com | jane@gmail.com | 2014-02-07 19:05:58
max@gmail.com   | wolf@gmail.com | 2014-03-12 09:03:12
```

Say that I am Steve, I want the "add" buttons text to now display "remove". In order to do that it would have to check the table to see if a row contains both "steve@gmail.com" and "jane@gmail.com". How do I do that? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 1**:
I tried the following:

```
$scan = $results[$counter];
$follow_email = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE name = '$scan'");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM follow WHERE follower = '$searcher_email' AND following = '$follow_email'");
if ($row['cnt'] == 0) {
$text212 = "Add";
}

 if ($row['cnt'] == 1) {
$text212 = "Remove";
}
```

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause. I.e: `WHERE Follower='steve@gmail.com' AND  Following='jane@gmail.com'`

Comment: Yes I understand. I'm testing it out right now. @Fred-ii-

Comment: Okay. After I have set up the query, how do I evaluate the result to see if the row exists or not? @Fred-ii-

Comment: You would check it with `mysqli_num_rows()` i.e.: `if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)` but you're using `mysql_*` I suggest you don't use that old function, use `mysqli_*` functions. So in your present case, it would be `if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)`

Comment: So what's been suggested hasn't worked for you?

Comment: Basically, you'd just need to do `$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Follower='steve@gmail.com' AND Following='jane@gmail.com'");` then `if(mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)` or `if(mysql_num_rows($query) ==1)` to check if both exits. Or this:  `$result = mysql_query("SELECT Follower, Following FROM members WHERE Follower='steve@gmail.com' AND Following='jane@gmail.com'");` --- You could replace the `AND` with an `OR` if you want to check if ONE or the other exists.

Comment: I have pasted my entire code above under UPDATE 2 @Fred-ii-

Comment: Sorry, that type of code in trying to piece everything together, is just a bit too overwhelming for me. I've given you the basics to check if a row exists etc.. I suggest you take it up with the people who have given you answers. If I knew more, I'd help you out more.

Comment: I will work with a clean slate then. Thank you for your explanations.

Comment: You're welcome. And do consider switching over to `mysqli_*` ;-) it's safer also. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
FROM Followers
WHERE Follower = 'steve@gmail.com' AND Following = 'jane@gmail.com'
```

Retrieve the row and test `$row['cnt']`. If it's 0, display `Add`; if it's 1, display `Remove`.

```
$scan = mysql_real_escape_string($results[$counter]);
$email_result = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM members WHERE name = '$scan'");
$email_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($email_result);
$follow_email = $email_row['email'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) cnt FROM follow WHERE follower = '$searcher_email' AND following = '$follow_email'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['cnt'] == 0) {
    $text212 = "Add";
} else {
    $text212 = "Remove";
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I pasted my implementation of this in my question as Update 1. Could you help me detect my mistake? @Barmar

Comment: You're missing the calls to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get the results of your queries.

Comment: Try reading a tutorial on how to use mysql from PHP, you seem to be very confused about it.

Comment: And since you're just starting out, let's avoid getting into bad habits. Learn how to use `PDO` or `mysqli` with parametrized queries, instead of substituting into the query.

Comment: Okay. I am having issues with mysqli. I will look more into what I may be doing wrong. How do I encorporate mysql_fetch_assoc() into all of this? I'm new to databases and tables, sorry.

Comment: I must have made a mistake somewhere. My entire code (css styling excluded) has been provided above under UPDATE 2.

Comment: Could you explain how it's failing? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: I get no errors. It follows through the code and the user being followed even gets a notification email! But when I click the follow button, it doesn't mention that I'm following the person, even if I am. It always says "add" no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what all the code is doing. Time to start putting `echo` statements into your code to see what the values of relevant variables are.

Comment: That's how I debug web pages when I can't figure out why they're not working, it's time for you to learn how to do it yourself.

Comment: Okay. You can view the physical page in action at [this link](http://lb.neon.org/engine/search.php?search=Ephraim). The provided link will search for me. I will get to that.

Comment: There's no way for me to tell what's happening on the server by viewing the resulting page.

Comment: Unfortunately. I am running a heap of tests and will notify you of the results.

Comment: I just noticed. If you want to see the contents of an array, use `var_dump` or `print_r`, not `echo`.

Comment: I found the bug. The system I used to fetch the current user return NULL. I will fix this. Thank you so much for all your help. Have a great rest of the day! @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM Followers
               WHERE Follower = 'steve@gmail.com' AND Following = 'jane@gmail.com')
```

Comment: Could you give me the whole command line. I am having a bit of trouble trying to figure out how to implement what you mentioned above. @abl

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution.

Comment: What I wrote is just the SQL query that will return whether the table contains a row with the indicated values. If you want your program to execute this query against the database, you must use the commands that your language provides. I'm afraid I am not familiar with PHP so I cannot help you with that. @Lite20